# How to output column in date format from moodle database?

Tags: moodle

I want to display column date in date format from moodle database:

View Code:

```
$table = new html_table();
$table->head = array('Date','Time', 'A' , 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F');
```

I'll be grateful for any reference or help on how to display date column in date format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `userdate()` it will display the date in the users locale.

```
userdate($scheduledatet)
```

EDIT: You can also specify the date/time format in the users locale by using `get_string()`

```
$dateformat = get_string('strftimedateshort', 'langconfig');

userdate($scheduledatet);
```

These are the English formats in /lang/en/langconfig.php

```
$string['strftimedate'] = '%d %B %Y';
$string['strftimedatefullshort'] = '%d/%m/%y';
$string['strftimedateshort'] = '%d %B';
$string['strftimedatetime'] = '%d %B %Y, %I:%M %p';
$string['strftimedatetimeshort'] = '%d/%m/%y, %H:%M';
$string['strftimedaydate'] = '%A, %d %B %Y';
$string['strftimedaydatetime'] = '%A, %d %B %Y, %I:%M %p';
$string['strftimedayshort'] = '%A, %d %B';
$string['strftimedaytime'] = '%a, %H:%M';
$string['strftimemonthyear'] = '%B %Y';
$string['strftimerecent'] = '%d %b, %H:%M';
$string['strftimerecentfull'] = '%a, %d %b %Y, %I:%M %p';
$string['strftimetime'] = '%I:%M %p';
```

Comment: no probs :) I just updated the answer for the date/time formats